# Device rotation results in NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I started working on an app based on the FragmentsBasic.zip sample project found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Before I started my own code, I imported ActionBarSherlock and got everything working as expected.

Situation: I have one main activity class (TaskListActivity) and 3 fragment classes.  When running the application in a phone TaskListActivity first loads the TaskListFragment and if the user touches the "new task" icon in the action bar it replaces the TaskListFragment with a NewTaskFragment. This fragment has a layout that contains an EditText and a Button View. When the user enters a text and presses the "done" button, the test gets added to the ListView.

Problem: Everything works as expected as long as no device rotation occurs. Regardless if I rotate the device before or after adding items to the list I get the following error,

```
10-18 23:19:40.838: E/TaskListActivity(2021): Fragment has a null value
10-18 23:19:40.848: E/AndroidRuntime(2021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 23:19:40.848: E/AndroidRuntime(2021): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-18 23:19:40.848: E/AndroidRuntime(2021):     at com.sample.testapp.TasksListActivity.onNewTaskAdded(TasksListActivity.java:169)
10-18 23:19:40.848: E/AndroidRuntime(2021):     at com.sample.testapp.NewTaskFragment$2.onClick(NewTaskFragment.java:63)
10-18 23:19:40.848: E/AndroidRuntime(2021):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2449)
10-18 23:19:40.848: E/AndroidRuntime(2021):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9027)
```

My Activity looks like this:

```java
public class TasksListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
        implements TasksListFragment.OnTaskSelectedListener,    NewTaskFragment.OnNewTaskAddedListener {

    private ArrayList<Task> tasks;
    private String taskName;
    private TasksListFragment firstFragment;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tasks_list);

            if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    return;
                }

            firstFragment = new TasksListFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_new:
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Tapped new task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // try code from Fragment sample
            NewTaskFragment newTaskFragment = (NewTaskFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.task_fragment);

            if(newTaskFragment != null){
                // if itemFragment is available we are in two-pane layout

                // Call method in NewItemFragment to update its content
                //itemFragment.
            }
            else{
                // if the frag is not available, we are in one-pane layout and must swap fragments

                // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
                newTaskFragment = new NewTaskFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                //args.putInt(NewItemFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
                newTaskFragment.setArguments(args);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view wiht this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newTaskFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();

            }
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

    public void onNewTaskAdded(String newItem){
        this.taskName = newItem;
        if(firstFragment == null){
            Log.e("TaskListActivity", "Fragment has a null value");
        }

        firstFragment.onItemAdded(this.taskName);  // This is line 169

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment);

        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

The NewItemFragment has the following (interface not shown):

```java
public class NewTaskFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_task_fragment, container, false);

    int layout = R.layout.new_task_fragment;
    Log.v("NewTaskFragment", "The layout to use is (NewTask): " + layout);

    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.newTask);
    final Button doneButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addNewTask);
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);


    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String newItem = myEditText.getText().toString();
            onNewTaskAddedListener.onNewTaskAdded(newItem);   // This is line 63
            myEditText.setText("");
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

I've highlighted with comments line 169 (Activity) and 63 (Fragment) which are getting flagged by the NullPointerException.  I added some code on onNewTaskAdded and was able to confirm that after rotation the fragment's value is null.  Can someone help me spot why the object is turning to null after rotation (hence the NullPointerException)? Let me know if additional details are needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

when u rotate your device, it will force to call onCreate() function, and savedInstanceState != null may be true now.

if u dont want to onCreate() again when it rotate, u can do like this:

firstly, add this line into your androidmanifest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

then modify your activity.java:

```
@Override  
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);  
  if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {  

  } else if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {  

  }  
}
```

Comment: Although for a phone I will use the same layout regarding of orientation, for a tablet I might have one layout for portrait and one for landscape, so not sure if ignoring configuration changes is the optimal solution. Each time a create a new instance of NewTaskFragment I make sure I add it to the back stack and since savedInstanceState is limited to basic data types, not sure what type of fragment retention/saving I have to do. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this snippets, This really is a big help. It took me 5 days to fix this and thanks to you i'm saved.